# How to create/edit SublimeText User Settings?

Tags: syntax, sublimetext3, settings

I'm trying to override `detect_indentation": false` in Sublime Text 3 (Windows 10). I've read that I shouldn't edit the `Settings - Default` since it resets on every update, but to instead go to `Settings - User`. But under my SublimeText 3 `Preferences` dropdown, I'm not seeing an option for `Settings - User`. I only have `Settings` (Default), `Settings - Syntax Specific` and `Settings - Distraction Free`.

Does this mean I have to dig into some files and actually create a `Settings - User` file? How and where do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In older versions of Sublime, there were two menu items for various preferences, one with `- Default` and one with `- User` appended to the end of them, where one of them would open the default file and the other would open your user specific files.

In Sublime Text build 3124, the menu items for this changed slightly. Where previously there were two sets of menu items, there is now one. Selecting that one item opens a new window that is split into two vertical panes.

The left pane contains a read-only version of the default settings, while the right pane shows your user defaults (creating a new file as needed if one does not yet exist).

So you just need to select the menu item appropriate for what you're trying to edit (preferences, key bindings, etc) and edit the contents of the right hand pane.

Answer (score 1):

**Settings - Default** can't be changed, but You can overwrite default property in **Settings - User** file.

In the same way You can configure *Syntax* or *Distraction*, also this rule work on all third-party packages. Sometimes configuration files missing in *Prefences* menu, but You can change properties in configuration file of the package, located in *sublime home* directory.